# Impossible to run Multithreading Python script with crontab

Tags: python, multithreading, cron

I have a issue with crontab on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS refused to run my Multithreaded python script.
My script work perfectly when i lauch it manually like :

```
sudo python my_script.py
```

But when i schedule it on crontab with :

```
21 23 * * * sudo /usr/bin/python /root/my_script.py 2>seo_error2.log
```

Impossible to run it properly, i have a Exception on Threading :

```
Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/root/my_script.py", line 152, in consumer
    foo(d, printlock, updatelock) #call our function from before
  File "/root/my_script.py", line 79, in foo
    print "Titre de la page:", titre
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: The issue is about encoding `print "Titre de la page:", titre`, the variable `title` contains non-ascii character. You should use UTF8, especially with languages like french.

Comment: The environment from where you run your script and the environment from where cron run its jobs isn't the same. The problem has to do with output encoding, not with multithreading as your question suggests. See http://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/02/locale-settings-for-your-cron-job/